# How to show hidden content of a sentence with click in angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the below html code,

```
<div class="item item-stacked-label" ng-repeat="item in cartItems" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" ng-model="item.name" style="max-width:50%;" ng-class="{'p': active,'showName': !active}" ng-click="active = !active" ><p >{{item.name}}</p></div>
    <div class="col" ng-model="item.qty" >{{item.qty}}</div>
    <div class="col" ng-model="item.price" >{{item.price}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the css,

```
.showName {
max-width: 100%;
}
p{
    color:#666;
    text-align:center;
 max-width: 50%;
}
```

I want to show the full details with the click. I have tried the above code but it is not working for me as I expected.

Below is the result I get. But I want to expand and show the content with the click. Please help
[image]

Comment: You seems to be adding class `p`... but you don't have a class definition for `p`... what you have is a tag selector?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] with the controller and rest of css creating ellispsis and such?

Comment: Your inline `style="max-width: 50%;"` overrides (higher specificity) the class properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind the car name to the `title` property of the div?That way whenever somebody hovers over the div with their mouse they will see the full name of the car, like this:

```
<div class="col" title="{{item.name}}" ng-model="item.name"><p>{{item.name}}</p></div>
```